# Add text in a div where find something

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div with id `content`. I want to search in this div `My Company` and then add after `My Company` the trade mark `®` symbol anywhere it appears in the div id=`content`. The problem is the text `My Company` isn't always in HTML as `My Company`. It could be `My <span style="something">C</span>ompany` or `My <font color="something">C</font>ompany` and I don't know how to add the `®` symbol after the text `My Company` even if it contains html tags in (as above).

I want to do this with JS/Jquery. Thank you so much!!!

Tried:

```
$("#content").each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    text = text.replace("My Company", "My Company®");
    $(this).text(text);
});
```

but it works only if it is `My Company` NOT when it is `My <span style="something">C</span>ompany` or `My <font color="something">C</font>ompany`

**EDIT**

I have one (single) div #content

**EXAMPLE**

```
<div id="content">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi et nisl quam. Praesent semper enim elit, vel imperdiet ipsum vulputate ac. Curabitur lacinia vitae metus sit amet consectetur.

My Company

Sed metus risus, iaculis a erat id, pretium congue nisi. Phasellus tempor, massa lobortis scelerisque pharetra, orci metus ultrices quam, eu sodales massa erat ut ipsum. Vestibulum ullamcorper interdum pretium. My <span style="color: orange;">C</span>ompany Praesent mollis in ex in feugiat. Ut vitae placerat diam. 
</div>
```

Comment: how many divs with `id=content` do you have?

Comment: you cant have more than one #content id.

Comment: Can u show your html  part

Comment: Personally I'd be looking at fixing the underlying content, instead of a clumsy jasvascript fix. If `My Company` is some thing that is consistently styled enclose it in a `<span>` with an appropriate class, You can then style the first letter with `::first letter` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Afirst-letter) and either add the TM in HTML or with CSS using `:after`. No javascript, no content flash or text reflow.

Comment: @LelioFaieta I have only one div with id `content`.

Comment: can you add the `®` character before placing that in html?

Comment: @MMPP As like this i added Varun Example this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nuvu2qmn/

Comment: then why are you using `.each()`? Each is needed to iterate through different elements in the dom that can be all grouped toghether. For example if you have more than one div with the same class and want to apply the code you are writing to all of them. This is not the option if you refer to a single div

Comment: What varun did is great but It will wipe out HTML structure of found element and will insert plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use classes if you want to have multiple divs with the same style on the page.

```
$("#content").each(function() {
    var text = $(this).html();
    text = text.replace(/My Company/g, "My Company<sup>®</sup>");
    text = text.replace(/My (<\/?span[^>]*>C\<\/span\>ompany)/g, "My Company<sup>®</sup>");
    text = text.replace(/My (<\/?font[^>]*>C\<\/font\>ompany)/g, "My Company<sup>®</sup>");
    $(this).html(text);
});
```

Comment: This is replacing HTML tags of second 'My Company'

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do it

```
$(function(){
$('#content').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(text.replace('My Company', 'My Company®')); 
});

});
```

**EDIT:**

May be thi **updated code** will work if you want to preserve the **HTML** as well

```
$(function(){
    var children = $('#content').children();
    children.each(function() {
    var text = $.trim($(this).text());
        if(text === 'My Company'){
            var getTagName = $(this).prop("tagName");
             var tagName = getTagName.toLowerCase();
             var replaceText = '<'+tagName+'>'+'My  Company®'+'</'+tagName+'>';
        $(this).html(replaceText); 
        }
       });
});
```

Check out the UPdated Fiddle **http://jsfiddle.net/69sv52y2/16/**

Comment: @downvoter: Please mention the reason for your downvote?

Comment: May be the updated code will preserve the html as well? Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Hi @IdentityUnkn0wn if my HTML structure this than http://jsfiddle.net/69sv52y2/21/

Comment: Oh...yes, may be its something that can be done with some complex regex which is not my strong side, but if its within the same tag, may be this will work :(

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can add like this right ?

```
$("#content").each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    if(text === 'My Company') {
       $(this).append('<span class="copyrightSymbol"> ® </span>');
    }
});
```

This will work. But `#content` is allowed only once in a page as it is an Id.

Comment: This will work only if the string is exactly "My Company". OP is asking something different

Comment: yes PP wants to add trade mark symbol after My Company inside #content. I think this will work. Please suggest. He doesn't want to change its structure. That's how it will also work

Comment: OP is asking to append it also when HTML is like this `My <span style="something">C</span>ompany or My <font color="something">C</font>ompany`

Comment: Hi I have checked in local. Its working fine for me. If any queries please make a js fiddle link and we will work on that

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#content").each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    text = text.replace(/My Company/g, "My Company®");
    $(this).text(text);
});
```

The earlier step which you were doing was right but you missed the global replace part.
jQuery `text()` will get only the text part inside the `div` tag. So no need to worry about the inner tags that are being wrapped.

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/srb8fusn/

Comment: But this will change his previous structure for 'C' in text. The span will get replaced by text right ?

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this problem due to multiple spaces between `my  company` 
When there is a `<span>`  tag inside the div then I guess your `HTML` is something like this `<div class='content'>  My <span> Company </span></div>` so there are two spaces between  `My`  and `Company` and your string replace is not working for that.

So you have to replace multiple spaces with single space first.

Working for these conditions too

```
My <font color="something">C</font>ompany

My <span style="something">C</span>ompany
```

Secondly If you are using multiple `dives` then you should use `class` instead of `id`

**Try this code:**

```
$(".content").each(function() {
        var text = $(this).text();
        console.log(text);
        text = text.replace(/ +(?= )/g,'').replace(/My Company/g, "My Company®");
        $(this).text(text);
    });
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/ishandemon/e9t7wjo8/

Answer (score 0):

You need to first strip of HTML tags around 'My Content', if there is any.

Then with plain text, search for it.

And if found, you can append a trademark at the end.

This will also preserve you original HTML markup of 'MY CONTENT'

**CONDITION:YOU MUST HAVE SINGLE 'MY CONTENT' inside div #content**

[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/69sv52y2/33/)

**CODE**

Basically I will create an HTML strip function to remove extra HTML tags around text and then search as shown in code below.

```
$(function(){
$('#content').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).html();
    console.log(text);
    console.log(stripHTML(text));
    if(stripHTML(text).indexOf("My Company")>-1)
    {
        alert("FOUND");
        $(this).html($(this).html() + "&reg;");
    }


});
function stripHTML(dirtyString) {
    var container = document.createElement('div');
    container.innerHTML = dirtyString;
    return container.textContent;
}
});
```